# Save results to a txt file python

Tags: python

I want to save these email results to my results.txt file in the directory.

```
def parseAddress():
    try:
        website = urllib2.urlopen(getAddress())
        html = website.read()

        addys = re.findall('''[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?''', html, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

        print addys

    except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
        print "Cannot retrieve URL: HTTP Error Code: ", err.code
    except urllib2.URLError, err:
        print "Cannot retrive URL: " + err.reason[1]

    # need to write the addys data to results.txt   
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
       result_line = f.writelines(addys)
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: It is not working... the data result from addys is not being saved to results.txt

Comment: Have you tried `f.write(addys)`?

Comment: I think you can print the text of `addys` first.

Comment: it keeps saying 'NameError: name 'addys' is not defined" Im not sure why

Comment: I would assume that's as a result of your defining `addys` within the `try` block. Define addys as an empty string (or multiline string) before your `try` block.

Comment: it is printing the text of addys on screen. but not saving the data to file.

Comment: Hmm...why you using ``result_line = f.writelines(addys)``? why not just ``f.write(addys)``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `return addys` at the end of your function. `print` will only output to your screen.

In order to retrieve `addys`, you would need to call the function in your `with` statement or create a variable that contains the result of `parseAddress()`.

You can save the memory that a variable would use by simply calling the function, like so:

```
with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write ( parseAddress() )
```

Answer (score 0):

You mistakenly indented the "with" statement one space.  This makes it subjective to an earlier block.  I would think any self-respecting Python interpreter would flag this as not matching any earlier indentation, but it seems to be fouling your output.

Also, please consider adding some tracing print statements to see where your code *did* execute.  That output alone can often show you the problem, or lead us to it.  You should always provide actual output for us, rather than just a general description.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your indentation, which is important in Python as it is the only way to define a block of code.

You also have too many statements in your `try` block.

```
def parseAddress():
    website = None
    try:
        website = urllib2.urlopen(getAddress())
    except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
        print "Cannot retrieve URL: HTTP Error Code: ", err.code
    except urllib2.URLError, err:
        print "Cannot retrive URL: " + err.reason[1]

    if website is not None:
        html = website.read()
        addys = re.findall('''[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?''', html, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        print addys

        # need to write the addys data to results.txt   
        with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
            result_line = f.writelines(addys)
```